# Isomorphism between groups with same presentation

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation

So say I have two groups $G$ and $H$. We let $G = \langle X \mid R\rangle$ and $H = \langle Y \mid R'\rangle$ where $|X| = |Y|$ and $R$ and $R'$ are the "same" relations. (For example if $(ab)^c = e$ is a relation in $R$ then there is the same relation in $R'$ aka there exists a relation $(a'b')^{c'} = e$.)

It seems that we should be able to define a simple isomorphism between $G$ and $H$ where each generator in $X$ gets sent to the appropriate generator in $Y$ such that all relations match up. I've been told that this map only gives us surjection which seems confusing as theoretically it should be inversable and thus be an isomorphism.

My question: Is it true that we only have a surjection in the case of a map

$$ \phi \colon G \rightarrow H$$

or can we actually show an isomorphism by identifying the appropriate generators together? If we don't have isomorphism, why is that?

Comment: You have obvious maps in both directions, and they're inverses to each other. I don't know who told you that you only get a surjection.

Comment: It seemed fairly obvious to me that they should be isomorphisms, but I wanted to double check because sometimes there are subtleties that I can miss. Thanks =)

Comment: I *think* the following holds: $R$ and $R'$ are **same** relations in your sense, this implies that there is also a bijection between *generating sets* $X$ and $Y$, and that bijection is homomorphism by basic properties of free groups and its quotients, so it is isomorphism

Comment: Suppose I print out your presentation on a printer. Then I print it again using a different font on a different printer. Do the presentations defined on my two bits of paper define isomorphic groups - or perhaps even the same group? It seems to me that this is equivalent to your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you define a map $G \to H$ with $\phi(a) = a'$  then it is clearly an isomorphism. Indeed if a combination of elements of $X$ belongs to $\ker f$ then   its image has to be identity in $H$.